# RTMPS , implementation not getting hit from client side

Tags: java, red5, rtmps

I m trying to implement rtmps on my red5 server. i have added the certificates i.e imported them to a key store and have uploaded them on the server. have enabled rtmps part on red5-core.xml .. This much part i.e

```
<!-- RTMPS -->

<bean id="rtmpsMinaIoHandler"
    class="org.red5.server.net.rtmps.RTMPSMinaIoHandler">
    <property name="handler" ref="rtmpHandler" />
    <property name="codecFactory" ref="rtmpCodecFactory" />
    <property name="rtmpConnManager" ref="rtmpMinaConnManager" />
    <property name="keyStorePassword" value="${rtmps.keystorepass}" />
    <property name="keystoreFile" value="conf/keystore" />
</bean>

<bean id="rtmpsTransport" class="org.red5.server.net.rtmp.RTMPMinaTransport" init-method="start" destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="ioHandler" ref="rtmpsMinaIoHandler" />
    <property name="connectors">
        <list>
            <bean class="java.net.InetSocketAddress">
                <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.lang.String" value="${rtmps.host}" />  
                <constructor-arg index="1" type="int" value="${rtmps.port}" />  
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="connectionThreads" value="${rtmp.connect_threads}" />
    <property name="ioThreads" value="${rtmp.io_threads}" />
            <property name="receiveBufferSize" value="${rtmp.receive_buffer_size}" />
    <property name="sendBufferSize" value="${rtmp.send_buffer_size}" />

            <!-- This is the interval at which the sessions are polled for stats. If mina monitoring is not
            enabled, polling will not occur. -->


    <property name="jmxPollInterval" value="1000" />
    <property name="tcpNoDelay" value="${rtmp.tcp_nodelay}" />
</bean>
```

The problem is when i try to hit my server with

```
rtmps://mysite:8443/red5server
```

I dont get a hit on my server. If as rtmps is not running at all. Any help or tutorial on configuring rtmps will be a grat help.